# Inverted switch case statement (until true)

Tags: php, algorithm, switch-statement

I am trying to achieve a result which I can only think of in terms of a reverse switch case until true statement. See regular case statement below:

```
 $i="bar";
   switch ($i) {
    case "apple":
        echo "i is apple.";
        break;
    case "bar":
        echo "i is bar.";
        break;
    case "cake":
        echo "i is cake.";
        break;
    }
```

The result I want is as follows:

Eg: if `$i = 'apple'` I want it to print `i is apple.`

Eg: if `$i = 'bar'` I want it to print `i is apple.i is bar.`

Eg: if `$i = 'cake'` I want it to print `i is apple.i is bar.i is cake`

The answer may not necessarily use the structure above once it can achieve the result

Comment: @hindmost that is `i is bar.i is cake` for $i="bar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$i = 'bar';

$cases = array(
    'apple' => 'i is apple.',
    'bar' => 'i is bar.',
    'cake' => 'i is cake.',
);

$resp = '';
foreach($cases as $k => $v)
{
    $resp .= $v;
    if($k == $i) break;
}

echo $resp;
?>
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/6HeIBcN8)

Comment: Nice answer. Not as intuitive to read, but definitly the most flexible to add more cases. +1

Answer (score 0):

This switch statement with fallthroughs is the most similar to the OP's that I can think of:

```
$i = "cake";
$output = "";

switch ($i) {
    case "cake":
        $output = "i is cake." . $output;
    case "bar":
        $output = "i is bar." . $output;
    case "apple":
        $output = "i is apple." . $output;
    default:
        echo $output;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just use a regular `IF` statement, but put the check AFTER the echo.

```
<?php
function checkMe($i) {
  echo "i is apple.";
  if ($i=="apple")
    return;

  echo "i is bar.";
  if ($i=="bar")
    return;

  echo "i is cake.";
  if ($i=="cake")
    return;
}

checkMe("bar");
?>
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/XgsCboiM)

Answer (score -1):

The switch would become like this:

```
$i="bar";

switch ($i)
{
    case "apple":
    case "bar":
    case "cake":

      echo "i is apple.";
      if ($i == "apple") break;

      echo "i is bar.";
      if ($i == "bar") break;

      echo "i is cake.";
      if ($i == "cake") break;

      default:
}
```